# Can't install pipelight using 13.10

Tags: 13.10, pipelight

I try to install Pipelight using this command line: `sudo apt-get install pipelight` and then I get this...

```
btcbro21@btcbro21-p7-1074:~$ sudo apt-get install pipelight
[sudo] password for btcbro21: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pipelight
```

I know that I typed it in right. Why won't it locate that package?

Comment: As RiotingPacifist said, this program isn't in the main package repository, as you can see here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pipelight&searchon=names&suite=saucy&section=all. Avinash Raj's answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

To install pipelight run the below commands on terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi
```

**source:** http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html

Answer (score 1):

Pipelight is not in the ubuntu repositories, to install it you must first add a PPA (**personal** package archive (a.k.a just some files some guy uploaded to launchpad))

The ppa you probably want is at https://launchpad.net/~mqchael/+archive/pipelight which can be added with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mqchael/pipelight`

Install it as your own risk, mqchael is probably a nice guy but he could be out to infect machines with malware.